# NGINX SSL has an error ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH for specific domain only

Tags: security, ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, cloudflare

unfortunately got `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` using cloudflare
It’s show something like below :

```
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.
```

I’m work with mutliple domain assume `example1.com` and `example2.com`.
`example1` and `example2` has same configuration except for the `server_name` and their `cert/private` pem of course.

`example1` are work great.
But `example2` is shown `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH`

**What I've Done :**

1. Clear SSL state and cookie and browser caches.
2. Use `SSLshoper` to check certificate but seem’s only at `example2` has fail.

Using NGINX as webserver.

Here a snippet of configuration :

nginx.conf

```
...
http {
  ...
  # SSL Settings
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
  ssl_session_cache   shared:SSL:10m;
  ssl_ciphers TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256;
  ...
  include /etc/nginx/cloudflare.inc;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

example1.conf

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name example1.com www.example1.conf;

    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/example1.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/example1.crt;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html/example1;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

}
```